# How should I stop pocket doors from scraping on the jamb?

Tags: doors, pocket-door

I have pocket doors that occasionally scrape on the inside on their frame which scuffs them up.

How should I protect against this?

I was thinking of using the soft side of velcro strips inside the frame.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I would guess that weatherstripping will cost less than velcro and provide the same function. There's also a question of "why sometimes" - if the door is swelling with humidity, it may bind on the soft padding and stick when it would have scraped.

Comment: Velcro is a fair short-term solution, but over time it will peel off, and Murphy's Law says it will stick deep in the door pocket interfering with the mechanism.  Best not to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a missing guide at the bottom of the door, much like a closet sliding door. Install one and it will prevent the door from moving side to side and it will stay centered and not rub.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Correct answer but that picture is showing the wrong location to install the guides. The bottom of the guides should be below the bottom of the door. Because the guides are thicker at their bottom, the slots for the screws allow adjustment. Higher will hold the door tighter, lower will give it some space and rub less.

Comment: @Olivier I've added another picture to show the pieces up close to show what you point out about the shape. Would you believe that I couldn't find a picture of them properly installed. This also moves the rub / contact to the bottom/face edge and away from the face so that here won't be an obvious wear pattern over time.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the guides can be hidden behind the trim, depending on how the door was trimmed out. This makes for a far neater looking installation.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer and keep them coming. And, you should probably take our [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here

Answer (score 0):

Image that shows proper installation of door guide.  Because of the angle, the rubbing will not be on the surface, but on the bottom edge of the door.  There also hidden door guides, but these may be specific to your brand.

[image: Door Guide Placement]